# Gradle Build error : com.couchbase.lite:couchbase-lite-android:2.1.0

Tags: android, react-native, android-gradle-plugin, couchbase-lite

I am trying to install `couchbase-lite` on react-native android project.
When I add dependency of couchbase-lite as explained in [here](https://docs.couchbase.com/couchbase-lite/2.1/java.html), it gives me the following error.

What I have tried

1. `react-native init MyProject`
2. add dependency `implementation 'com.couchbase.lite:couchbase-lite-android:2.1.0'` to my `./android/app/build.gradle` file
3. `react-native run-andoid`

Then found following error

```
Could not find method implementation() for arguments [com.couchbase.lite:couchbase-lite-android:2.1.0] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
```

Does anyone have an explanation or solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question,

Issue got fixed after upgrading gradle into `v4.10` and gradle wrapper plugin into `v3.1.0`

./app/build.gradle

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0'
...
ext {
minSdkVersion = 19
...
```

./app/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10-bin.zip
```

then

```
react-native run-android
```